# Problem with spark.implicits._ in Jupyter with Spylon-Kernel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an inexplicable problem importing "spark.implicits._" into Jupyter Notebook with the Spylon-Kernel interpreter. The code I was testing is very simple and is the following:

```
   val spark = SparkSession.builder
                           .appName("DataFrameAddingLiterals")
                           .getOrCreate()
   import spark.implicits._

   val columns = Seq("name","age","weight", "height")
   val data = Seq(("Jose", 40, 74, 1.63), ("María Isabel", 38, 58, 1.65), ("Antonio", 27, 60, 1.68), 
                  ("Norma", 63, 65, 1.54))

   val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

   df.show()
```

The code works perfectly in Databricks (without the sparksession) and in Intellij. In Jupyter Notebook at the time of importing "implicits" it is blocked without giving any type of error but without working.

Does anyone know what the reason may be or if it is a bug?

Comment: "it is blocked without giving any type of error but without working." Then how do you know it is blocked or it is not working? Is there any info/log messages?

Comment: The * symbol stays in the chunk and does not execute the rest of the codes. As if it was still processing. I can include photos if it helps.

Comment: Try separating the cell into different cells, preferably one line per cell. Run the cells one by one to find out which cell is not working.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/G0Kzys9) Image of the problem. The same code works without problem in Intellij and Databricks

Comment: I just found (thanks to your advice to separate the code) the error and it is even more disturbing. The error comes from "María Isabel", I have to put it without accent for it to work. Now I need to know why the accent fails in the letter.

Comment: probably some encoding problems